# Get total in FormArray Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to get the values of an input in each row and get the sum of these rows.

my HTML:

```
<ng-container formArrayName="cap_values">
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of capValues.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <tr>
            <td class="freeze-first-col"><input type="text" (blur)="getName(item.value.name)" formControlName="name"></td>
            <td><input type="number" formControlName="fdnTotalShares"</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</ng-container>
```

my .ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    cap_values: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      fdnTotalShares: '',
    }
    )])
  })
}
```

How do I iterate over each value in the array and sum it? I have seen `.valueChanges` but am not entirely sure how to use it.

Comment: When do you want the sum of rows?

Comment: @AbuTaha i have a `(keyup.enter)` function after keying in the value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, I'll write down some:

1st way:

```
get capValues(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('cap_values') as FormArray;
}

getSum() {
    this.sum = this.capValues.value.reduce((prev, next) => prev + +next.fdnTotalShares, 0);
    // OR
    // this.sum = this.capValues.getRawValue().reduce((prev, next) => prev + +next.fdnTotalShares, 0);
}
```

*Notice the `+` sign in `+next.fdnTotalShares`, that is not a mistake, it is to make sure that you get the sum of numbers (assuming `fdnTotalShares` will always be a number) instead of getting string concatenation.*

2nd way:

```
this.sum = 0;
this.capValues.value.forEach(x => {
      this.sum += +x.fdnTotalShares;
});
```

Instead of `value` you can use `getRawValue()` if you have some controls that are disabled and you want to include them in your calculation.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksgq2y) is a stackblitz example demonstrating this (I also included the difference with `enabled` and `disabled` controls).

**EDIT**: To answer you question in the comment, this is similar as the sum example I wrote above:

```
multiplyAndStore() {
    const multiplicationRes = this.capValues.value.reduce((prev, next) => prev * +next.fdnTotalShares, 1);
    // Assuming that "formControlName" for multiplication result input is 'multiplyResult'
    this.form.get('multiplyResult').setValue(multiplicationRes);
    // You can also use "patchValue" method instead of "setValue"
    // this.form.get('multiplyResult').patchValue(multiplicationRes);
}
```

I have updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weferc) example so you can see this in action.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes thanks so much! i have another question. suppose i have 2 input boxes. i would like to multiple the value of these 2 and display it in another box. how can i retrieve the value from the multiplication and use it? this other textbox has a formControlName

Comment: I have updated the answer to include answer for this comment. You multiply any way you want (I multiplied values in the array in this example) and you set that result in another input.

Comment: hi sorry only saw your answer to my comment. the two values that i would like to multiply is not the same `FormControl`. Its is at the same `FormArray`, but is a different `FormControl`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `valueChanges` Observable to achieve this.

In your component, once you create your form, subscribe to the `valueChanges` in your form array `cap_values`.

```js
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

total: number = 0;
subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    // Create your form here

    this.subscription = this.capValues.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
        this.total = data.reduce((a,b) => a + +b.fdnTotalShares, 0)
    });
}

get capValues() {
    return this.form.get('cap_values') as FormArray;
}
```

Now wherever you want to display the total in your template just use `{{total}}` and it will dynamically update as you change values in the `fdnTotalShares` input.

Lastly, do not forget to unsubscribe from `valueChanges`. This is why I have introduced the `subscription` variable as seen in the code snippet above.

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Here is a simple working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-total).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your form controls

```
let total = 0;
form.controls.foreach(data => {
  total += data.fdnTotalShares.value;
})
```

To make sure proper form control is being get use console log

Answer (score 0):

Here I have Tried . [One](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-add-angular-material-auto-complete-in-formarray-2fkaqq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
 console.log(this.form.length);
 console.log(this.form.value);
```